# Mostrar Listado en un DatagridVieW vb

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013

Bueno le comento que estoy realizando un listado de archivo en un datagridView
para ellos estoy usando las herramientas de :

Sql server
Visual Basic Window Form

si me muestra pero cuando le presiono clic me genera y abre varios formulario como la imagen. Como podria realizar para que los campos solo se muestren en un formulario y ordenada hacia abajo Este es mi codigo primero cuando le doy generar del FORM 1:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim objReader As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        Dim sLine As String = ""
        Dim arrText As New ArrayList()

        Do
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then

                arrText.Add(sLine)

            End If
        Loop Until sLine Is Nothing

        objReader.Close()
        Using Con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexion").ConnectionString)
            Con.Open()
            For Each sLine In arrText
                Using command As New SqlCommand("RegistrarDatosTxt", Con)

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opt", 1)


                    command.Parameters.Add("@numerocredito", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = sLine

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Se Generaron Correctamente los Numero de Creditos", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..")

                    Dim frm As New Form2
                    frm.Show()

                End Using
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo formulario que muestra es este codigo:

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim oConn As SqlConnection
        oConn = New SqlConnection("Server=192.168.105.150\SQL2012;database=credito;uid=sa;pwd=DBServ@14;")
        If oConn.State = 1 Then oConn.Close()
        oConn.Open()
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim Adp As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Adp.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand() ' Creando una Instancia de SqlCommand
        Adp.SelectCommand.Connection = oConn 'Conexión
        Adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "RegistrarDatosTxt"
        Adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@opt", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
        Adp.SelectCommand.Parameters("@opt").Value = 2
        Adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@numerocredito", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)
        Adp.SelectCommand.Parameters("@numerocredito").Value = ""
        Adp.Fill(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo como esto. Espero que te ayude

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ctm002. Gracias por la respuesta. Solo a modo de recordatorio, tanto en las preguntas como las respuestas, es preferible incluir código como texto en vez de imagenes. Eso facilita que alguien pueda conseguir la información por búsqueda en el web y también facilita copiar el código. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar pero igual no me sale el mismo error. se genera varias veces yo solo quiero que salga asi 

<img src="http://example.com/Captura2.jpg" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo resolvi puse este codigo fuera del bucle.

  Dim frm As New Form2

            frm.Show()

Comment: #FriendlyReminder Ha pasdo un tiempo y la respuesta sigue como imagen.